# Debugging an application on VmWare with CDB in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I'am trying to debug the qt application which i made and placed on VmWare. I followed this guide https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_devices_serial_host_app_to_vm.html

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_devices_serial_advanced_example_debugging.html

I have the 'cdb' debugger installed so my  vmware shared pipe is `\\.\pipe\com_1` i'm running the `cdb` with arguments: `cdb -server npipe:pipe=\\.\pipe\com_1 -v C:\tests\clean_deploy\app.exe` on the Virtual Machine. I'am assuming that cdb will use the `\\.\pipe\com_1` to listen for the connections. On my OS(Windows 7) i run the qt->debugging->attach to remote cdb session and set the connection string like this `npipe:server=server,pipe=\\.\pipe\com_1` 
And i get in qt log:

```
Debugging Started
Debugging Finished
```

Without anything.

How do you debug an application on the vmware with cdb server using external pipe, from the qt cdb enviroment ??

Comment: IMHO Qt Creator is a nice environment (builds quick and good editor) overall but CDB is pathetic against Visual Studio own debugger and btw there is an add-in for both Qt (1.2.3 version works for me) and VMWare.

Comment: @AlexanderVX so you suggest to install qt addin for visual studio, and compile the project in there, then use visual studio debugger because it works with vmware? No way to attach cdb to vmware somehow?

Comment: I do suggest that because Visual Studio debugger experience is way better. Or you can have a lot of fun but waste a bit too much time.